# Catch the fn keys in Google TV

Tags: javascript, google-tv

I work on the Logitech Revue Google TV and i've to catch the fn keys in order to show the menu.

I trace the log and no event is fired when i press fn + 9 (MENU)

Comment: There is a menu key in the logitech remote, and when the user presses that key the Activity menu implemented using the standard Android way of implementing menu shows up. Why do you want to not use the standard way?